# Downsides of brewing espresso with high pressure?

Tags: brewing-process, espresso, crema

The [Italian National Espresso Institute](http://www.espressoitaliano.org/en/) requires the following properties for a [*certified* Espresso](http://www.espressoitaliano.org/files/File/istituzionale_inei_hq_en.pdf):

- Water pressure: 9 bar ± 1
- Percolation time: 25 seconds ± 5 seconds

I'm using a Quickmill Pegaso 3035, and for some coffees I do have a much higher pressure (around 12-16 bar). However, the percolation time is around 25 seconds, the coffee has a good crema and tastes fine.

Are there any downsides because of the high pressure? Does it alter the taste? Would I get more crema if I reduced the pressure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A higher pressure is fine, as long as it is a controlled variable. You may have to tamp harder or start with a finer grind in order to accommodate the higher pressure. The increase in pressure otherwise would cause a faster brewing time and ergo underextraction of the coffee puck.

What's important is that you keep your pressure consistent. An *occasional* or *erratic* bout of high pressure makes your yield unpredictable.